# Enumerating geometric solutions programmatically

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, brute-force

I have 81 vertices and need to connect each one to exactly 20 others. How could I brute force the number of possible answers? All I know about the answer is that it probably has a lot of digits.

Comment: I hesitate to guess the number of digits in the number of digits.

Comment: What should an answer be here? Pseudocode? Or an implementation in an arbitrary curly-brace-language? In any case, my gut feeling is that your last statement is important: There will probably be ***MANY*** solutions. So you want an algorithm that *theoretically* enumerates all these 10^1000 solutions? Or an implementation that *actually* shows how this can be done, but maybe not with 81/20 vertices, but with 20/4 vertices? Or only an answer showing how to compute *how many* solutions there are (**without** enumerating them)?

Comment: There are 80 choose 20 = 3.5e18 possible ways to choose the connections to the *first* vertex.  You do not have a computer fast enough to brute force this in your lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Firstly, the number of ways to select exactly 20 others when you have 81 vertices is "80 take 20". That's already 3535316142212174320. Then you essentially have a base-3535316142212174320 number of 81 digits, and you would increment that counter until you've had all the numbers. How many numbers? base<sup>length</sup> - I'm not even going to paste the entire number here, it's about 2.6 * 10<sup>1502</sup>.

So as for brute force, just no. That's not uncommon in combinatorics.